# Udev rule is not being used?

Tags: arch-linux, udev, automounting, block-device

I'm setting up `udev` to handle my external USB hard drive when it gets plugged in and removed (no mounting yet). So far, I've made two new rules in `/etc/udev/rules.d/10-local.rules` to log adding/removing the disk to a file:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTRS{model}=="2AS", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/echo 'inserted lacie' >> /home/herman/udev_file"
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTRS{model}=="2AS", ACTION=="remove", RUN+="/bin/echo 'removed lacie' >> /home/herman/udev_file"
```

I have started the `udevd` daemon and re-plugged the hard drive several times, but `/home/herman/udev_file` is never created . In the rules I've used keys from the command [`udevadm info -a -n /dev/sdb`](http://pastebin.com/2NTpX4Yu) which is the hard drive in question. What am I doing wrong here? The disk is being detected and I'm able to `mount` it just fine. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`udev` outputs logging information to `/var/log/messages`, but by default it only logs errors, and it happens you've constructed a command that doesn't do what you want, but also doesn't error out. The `>>` redirection is handled by your shell, and udev doesn't run the command through a shell, so it's literally running the binary `/bin/echo` and passing it the arguments `'inserted lacie' >> /home/herman/udev_file`. If you change udev to log more (edit `/etc/udev/udev.conf` and add the line `udev_log="info"`), you'll see that it runs that command, and the output is `'inserted lacie' >> /home/herman/udev_file`

Personally, I prefer making short shell scripts that do what I want, so I can edit them without restarting `udev`, but you can also use `/bin/sh -c` to run your command so it will process the redirection:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", ATTRS{model}=="2AS", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/bin/sh -c '/bin/echo inserted lacie >> /home/herman/udev_file'"
```

Comment: Thanks, I did replace the `echo` line with an executable script and it did work. Your example above worked for me when using absolute path to `sh`: `RUN+="/bin/sh -c '..'"`. Now my problem is different - the "add" action is called several times - I can't seem to match the usb drive "uniquely" enough.

Comment: `/bin/sh` <--absolute path seems like an essential component. Worked for me this way too in Arch Linux.