# udev rule not working

Tags: debian, usb, udev

I have created a `udev` rules which is supposed to mount a USB device, backup some datas et cleanup everything. I am actually working on a `Debian` server.

There is the information about my usb device that I have with `lsusb`

> Bus 001 Device 003: ID 054c:0243 Sony Corp. MicroVault Flash Drive

(Actually the `lsusb` returns more Bus / Device, but I have to write them by hand since I am not posting from my Debian machine :))

Then I have written my `udev` rule called :

```
10-usb_back.rules
```

into:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/
```

(I used 95 because the backup script takes some seconds and I want to run it as late as I can for avoiding to delay other stuff)

And finally the rule itself:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="054c", ATTR{idProduct}=="0243", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/mount_usb"
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="054c", ATTR{idProduct}=="0243", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/backup_database"
```

I have tried this too:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="054c", ATTR{idProduct}=="0234", RUN+="bash /usr/local/bin/mount_usb"
```

Unsuccessfully :(

Then I restart `udev`

```
sudo /etc/init.d/udev restart
```

And when I plug my USB device I got this weird message:

> [1348.295280] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdc] Assuming drive cache: write through

twice

But nothing happened. No USB device mounted, no data backed up.

```
I looked with tail -f /var/log/message
```

And the USB drive looks like detected:

```
usb 1-3: Product Storage Media 
usb 1-3 Manufacturer Sony`
...
```

Something must be wrong somewhere but I don't know what, neither where :(

Edit: Since I've been a little bit lazy because I can't rewrite everything from my server, please ask for further information if needed, such as the script or more logs messages :)

Comment: You can use the command at http://raftaman.net/?p=343 to check for more information on the usb drive. Also, the C program on the bottom of https://www.kernel.org/doc/pending/hotplug.txt is really useful for listening to uevents, which makes it easier to see what information you can use. Could also be as simple as some earlier rule is declared as final rule.

Comment: I will take a look at the C program, but it's looks like a little bit tricky, isn't it?

Comment: Somewhat, but you don't need to understand it. It is useful as a util :). Btw, I think you misspelled ATTR, should be ATTRS for usb properties.

Comment: I had the same problem a while ago. Mabye [that solution](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/40387/13742) will work for you too.

Comment: @don_crissti After running udevadm test --action --add /dev/sdc1 (I dont have a devpath directory, I guess devpath is the usb device path?) I had a list of rules, but mine didnt appear and I got a `unable to open device '/sys/dev/sdc1'`

Comment: So, I've been busy last week with an emergency. So I ran the command `udevadm test --action=add /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.7/usb1/1-3`and the ouput is a list with some informations about my device, such as ID_VENDOR, ID_MODEL,...

Comment: you can check what is happening with `unbuffer udevadm monitor --environment`. `unbuffer` is in `expect-dev` and ensures that your output is continuously updated (rather than buffered in 4kB blocks causing you sometimes to mis the last messages).

Answer (score 2):

This is my working udev rule for executing backup on hotplug:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block" ACTION=="add" \
      ENV{DEVTYPE}=="partition" \
      ENV{ID_FS_UUID}=="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx" \
      TAG+="store" \
      RUN+="/usr/bin/python3 /etc/systemd/autoback.py --udev"
```

Note that instead of matching the USB device, I'm matching a partition (i.e. `/dev/sde1`) on the mass storage endpoint of that usb device. It takes a few seconds after the USB hotplug before the disk is ready and the partition is enumerated so this is the "right" event for my use case, and probably yours too if you're trying to do backups. `ID_FS_UUID` is the same as reported by `blkid` for this partition. In my case, this is the `luks` UUID.

On my system udev doesn't seem to automatically reload correctly when I edit rules, but what I've found to work (which is also useful for debugging) is:

```
udevadm test /sys/dev/block/8:65
```

to force a reload/re-application of udev rules. Note that I found `8:65` by `ls -l /dev/block | grep sde1`. Also

```
udevadm info --query=property /dev/sde1
```

was helpful to see if my rules are applied, and

NOTE: I'm posting this answer 5 years after the OP, so things might be different now than then. My system is ubuntu 16.04.4 (xenial) on arm64.

Answer (score 1):

You have misspelled ATTR, it should be ATTRS in this case.

Comment: Don't know why, but it still no working, I losing any hope for making this stuff working :( Thank you for your contribution

Comment: Writing udev rules is a very unforgiving task, the slightest error and nothing will happen. Have you tried moving your rule to the beginning of the list? i.e., rename the file `to 10-local.rules`

Comment: Also did you restart udev after making changes? udev should react to changes in the settings, but that require inotify to be enabled in the kernel. That might not be the case in embedded systems and the like.

Comment: I restarted the local server, shall I retart udev too?

Comment: If you restarted the computer, then udev was already restarted.

Comment: I changed the name to 10-usb_backup.rules, still not working

Answer (score 1):

Try having a look at the output for `udevadm info --path=path/to/device --attribute-walk` It will tell you every attribute and subsystem that's valid for the device. For instance, a USB device I have has a `SUBSYSTEM="tty"`, to recognize USB for that device you need to put `SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"` (note: plural subsystem**s**). I suspect that something like that may be the case here. Either way `udevadm info --attribute-walk` is a really helpful tool for debugging udev problems.

Also ATTR{key} is not valid, instead use ATTRS{key} (It was mentioned before, but some of your examples still use the incorrect form.)

Answer (score 0):

Aren't those typos in the `idProduct` portion of the rules?

You have this:

```
ATTR{idProduct}=="0234"
```

Shouldn't it be this:

```
ATTR{idProduct}=="0243"
```

Based on the output from this line:

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 054c:0243 Sony Corp. MicroVault Flash Drive
```

Comment: You got a point, i fixed it but still not working, anyway thanks for pointing that out :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be plural too? (`ATTRS`)

Comment: @AlexisWilke - look at other A'ers didn't seem to make a diff.