# Udev Rule Isn't Used

Tags: udev, angstrom

I'm trying to write a udev rule on my Beaglebone White that runs when a Pantech UML 295 finishes booting.

When using `udevadm monitor --environment` I get the following final output which I would like to base the rule on:

```
UDEV [3163.454297] add /devices/platform/omap/musb-ti81xx/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-
1:1.0/net/eth1 (net)
ACTION=add
DEVPATH=/devices/platform/omap/musb-ti81xx/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1/1-1:1.0/net/eth1
ID_BUS=usb
ID_MODEL=PANTECH_UML295
ID_MODEL_ENC=PANTECH\x20UML295
ID_MODEL_ID=6064
ID_REVISION=0228
ID_SERIAL=Pantech__Incorporated_PANTECH_UML295_UML295692146818
ID_SERIAL_SHORT=UML295692146818
ID_TYPE=generic
ID_USB_DRIVER=cdc_ether
ID_USB_INTERFACES=:020600:0a0000:030000:
ID_USB_INTERFACE_NUM=00
ID_VENDOR=Pantech__Incorporated
ID_VENDOR_ENC=Pantech\x2c\x20Incorporated
ID_VENDOR_ID=10a9
IFINDEX=6
INTERFACE=eth1
SEQNUM=1151
SUBSYSTEM=net
SYSTEMD_ALIAS=/sys/subsystem/net/devices/eth1
TAGS=:systemd:
USEC_INITIALIZED=3163023666
```

My udev rule version 1:

```
ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb", SUBSYSTEM=="net", RUN+="/home/root/rebootInternetConnection.sh", ENV{ID_MODEL}=="PANTECH_UML295", ACTION=="add", INTERFACE=="eth1", ENV{ID_USB_DRIVER}=="cdc_ether"
```

and version 2:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", RUN+="/home/root/rebootInternetConnection.sh"
```

Version 2 is a stripped down version which should be ran more than once, but doesn't get ran at all. Version 1 uses environment variables which I'm not sure whether or not the rule has access to.

To clarify: the rule doesn't get ran at all, and the shell script has echos which should show up. My rule is in the /etc/udev/rules.d/ directory with name 10-local.rules.

**EDIT**

Here are some more non-functional rules, placed in /etc/udev/rules.d/81-pantech.rules:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", ATTR{idVendor}=="10a9", RUN+="/home/root/reboot
InternetConnection.sh"

SUBSYSTEM=="net", ATTR{idVendor}=="10a9", ATTR{idProduct}=="6064", RUN+="/home/ro
ot/rebootInternetConnection.sh"

ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="hid", RUN+="/home/root/rebootInternetConnection.sh"

ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", RUN+="echo foo > /tmp/foo"

SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{product}=="PANTECH UML295", RUN +="echo foo > /tmp/foo"

ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{product}=="PANTECH UML295", RUN+="/home/ro
ot/rebootInternetConnection.sh"
```

When I run:

```
udevadm test /devices/platform/omap/musb-ti81xx/musb-hdrc.1/u
```

it returns the last couple of lines as:

```
run: 'echo foo > /tmp/foo'
run: 'echo foo > /tmp/foo'
run: 'echo foo > /tmp/foo'
run: '/home/root/rebootInternetConnection.sh'
```

Is there a case where the rules will add to the RUN+=, but don't get used?

Comment: Does it run if you use something even simpler like `ls`? Also, do you actually _have_ a `/home/root` directory? Root's $HOME is usually `/root`.

Comment: *"Version 1 uses environment variables which I'm not sure whether or not the rule has access to."* -- I believe that is correct, you don't get any ENV stuff for "add" events.  Your echo's are not going to show up anywhere, but you can use the `logger` command to pipe stuff to syslog.

Comment: Possible answer here: [udev-rule-is-not-being-used](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/40387/udev-rule-is-not-being-used).

Comment: @terdon When I `pwd` I get `/home/root`.

Comment: @terdon `ls` Doesn't run either.

Comment: Your second rule has no specific device. Try adding `ATTRS{idVendor}=="10a9"` to your rule and just give `echo foo > /tmp/foo` or something as the command to run.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you could have too few arguments.

Comment: @terdon `ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", ATTRS{idVendor}=="10a9", RUN+="echo foo > /tmp/foo"` doesn't run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what changed, but the rule is now being used in the file /etc/udev/rules.d/81-pantech.rules

One possibility is the missing /run/udev/rules.d/ directory. When I ran

```
udevadm test /devices/platform/omap/musb-ti81xx/musb-hdrc.1/usb1/1-1
```

I got a line reporting that the directory was missing. I found this command through this guide: http://weininger.net/how-to-write-udev-rules-for-usb-devices/

```
mkdir /run/udev/rules.d/
```

Another possibility is me manually running the udev daemon with

```
/lib/udev/udevd --debug
```

This is my final rule:

```
ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{product}=="PANTECH UML295", RUN+="/home/root/rebootInternetConnection.sh"

ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="net", ATTR{idVendor}=="10a9", RUN+="/home/root/rebootInternetConnection.sh"
```